# docker-compose : variables from .env not available in the service

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, typeorm

I'm new to nodejs and I can't figure out why environment variables are not always available.

Env vars in my `.env` are parsed by docker-compose automatically. So I'm not using the dotenv package.

```
console.log(process.env.API_URL) // outputs undefined
```

But in an asynchronous function (maybe it doesn't work in all async functions)

```
async function foo() {
    console.log(process.env.API_URL) // outputs http://example.com
}
```

After moving a few ways the console.log in my `index.ts`, I've found the line where env vars become available :

```
// index.ts
import {createConnection} from 'typeorm'
console.log(process.env.API_URL) // outputs undefined
createConnection()
console.log(process.env.API_URL) // outputs http://example.com
```

Any idea on why this is happening ?

**Edit :**

I'm using this docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./docker-build
      target: server-develop
    ports:
      - "3200:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/app
    command: "yarn run dev"
```

[Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#pass-environment-variables-to-containers) seems to tell that the `.env` file is parsed by default when env_file is not specified. Screenshot from docker documentation :

[image: docker-compose reference]

However I don't see env vars when using `docker-compose exec server env`.
But if I specify the `env_file` in the `docker-compose.yml` (see below), environment vars are correctly loaded.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./docker-build
      target: server-develop
    env_file: .env # the only change
    ports:
      - "3200:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/app
```

Maybe I misunderstood what actually docker does when It says

> The .env file is loaded by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dotenv` from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Probably you are using nodemon and as far as I know it only loads the NODE_ENV variable. By using `dotenv` you can just:

- create a new file `.env` in root folder where you put your env variables
- as early as possible you load `require('dotenv').config()`

You'll find more information on the npmjs package page itself like changing your startup command so it can automatically load `.env` file and more

Comment: Thanks but I want environment vars to be parsed by the docker engine, and available on the container before nodejs has started.

Comment: Np. Just run docker mentioning the file 
`sudo docker run [...] --env-file ./my_env.list [...]`
or mention your variable in docker-compose file in path `services -> client-side-app -> environment -> MY_VAR = "my-var" `

Comment: You're right, however I've edited my question to precise what I expected about docker env parsing